# Merge tables with SQL-like join with filter (Between) in left join

Tags: python, pandas, t-sql, join, filter

So I have these two tables where I want to do a `left join` and filter the rows where my `date` column from `df1` is between the `from` and `to` columns from `df2`.

Pay attention to `row 6` which has no `ClockInDate` which eventually will cause the problem.

**df1**:

```
  Company Resource ClockInDate
0       A     ResA  2019-02-09
1       A     ResB  2019-02-09
2       A     ResC  2019-02-09
3       B     ResD  2019-02-09
4       B     ResE  2019-02-09
5       B     ResF  2019-02-09
6       B     ResG         NaT
```

**df2**:

```
  Company Resource EffectiveFrom EffectiveTo
0       A     ResA    2018-01-01  2018-12-31
1       A     ResA    2019-01-01  2099-12-31
2       A     ResB    2018-01-01  2018-12-31
3       A     ResB    2019-01-01  2099-12-31
4       B     ResE    2018-01-01  2018-12-31
5       B     ResE    2019-01-01  2099-12-31
6       B     ResF    2018-01-01  2018-12-31
7       B     ResF    2019-01-01  2099-12-31
8       B     ResG    2018-01-01  2018-12-31
9       B     ResG    2019-01-01  2099-12-31
```

I thought I can do this with `left merge` in pandas and after that apply a filter.
But it gives a different output.

So in SQL you can include this filter in the `ON` clause like this, but it is not the same as including this after the join in the `WHERE` clause:

```
       SELECT t1.company,
              t1.resource,
              t2.company,
              t2.resource,
              t1.ClockInDate,
              t2.EffectiveFrom,
              t2.EffectiveTo
       FROM table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.resource = t2.resource
                            AND t1.company = t2.company
                            AND t1.ClockInDate BETWEEN t2.EffectiveFrom AND t2.EffectiveTo
```

**Notice** the part: `AND t1.ClockInDate BETWEEN t2.EffectiveFrom AND t2.EffectiveTo`
**Notice:** in SQL code `df1` is `t1` and `df2` is `t2`

**SQL Output** (Which is my expected output):

```
    t1.Company  t1.Resource t1.ClockInDate  t2.EffectiveFrom    t2.EffectiveTo
0   A           ResA        2019-02-09      2019-01-01          2099-12-31
1   A           ResB        2019-02-09      2019-01-01          2099-12-31
2   A           ResC        NaT             NaT                 NaT
3   B           ResD        NaT             NaT                 NaT
4   B           ResE        2019-02-09      2019-01-01          2099-12-31
5   B           ResF        2019-02-09      2019-01-01          2099-12-31
6   B           ResG        NaT             NaT                 NaT
```

So I this is my code in `Python`:

**Python Output**

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Company', 'Resource'], how='left')
df_final = df_merge[df_merge.ClockInDate.between(df_merge.EffectiveFrom, df_merge.EffectiveTo) | df_merge.EffectiveFrom.isnull()]

#Output:

    Company Resource    ClockInDate EffectiveFrom   EffectiveTo
1   A       ResA        2019-02-09  2019-01-01      2099-12-31
3   A       ResB        2019-02-09  2019-01-01      2099-12-31
4   A       ResC        2019-02-09  NaT             NaT
5   B       ResD        2019-02-09  NaT             NaT
7   B       ResE        2019-02-09  2019-01-01      2099-12-31
9   B       ResF        2019-02-09  2019-01-01      2099-12-31
```

So notice that the last row with resource `ResG` is not included in my Python output.

**Copy and paste-able** code to reproduce `DataFrames`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Company':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'Resource':['ResA', 'ResB','ResC', 'ResD', 'ResE', 'ResF', 'ResG'],
                    'ClockInDate':['2019-02-09', '2019-02-09', '2019-02-09', '2019-02-09', '2019-02-09', '2019-02-09', '']})

df1['ClockInDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.ClockInDate)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Company':['A','A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'Resource':['ResA', 'ResA', 'ResB', 'ResB', 'ResE', 'ResE', 'ResF', 'ResF', 'ResG', 'ResG'],
                    'EffectiveFrom':['2018-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'],
                    'EffectiveTo':['2018-12-31', '2099-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2099-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2099-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2099-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2099-12-31']})

df2['EffectiveFrom'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.EffectiveFrom)
df2['EffectiveTo'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.EffectiveTo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working on this project I gained some more insight. I found a solution but was hoping for a `cleaner` one. But this works: we can concat the rows from the original dataframe which have `ClockIndate.isnull`:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Company', 'Resource'], how='left')

df_filter = df_merge[df_merge.ClockInDate.between(df_merge.EffectiveFrom, df_merge.EffectiveTo) | df_merge.EffectiveFrom.isnull()]

df_final = pd.concat([df_filter, df1[df1.ClockInDate.isnull()]], sort=True)

print(df_final)
  ClockInDate Company EffectiveFrom EffectiveTo Resource
1  2019-02-09       A    2019-01-01  2099-12-31     ResA
3  2019-02-09       A    2019-01-01  2099-12-31     ResB
4  2019-02-09       A           NaT         NaT     ResC
5  2019-02-09       B           NaT         NaT     ResD
7  2019-02-09       B    2019-01-01  2099-12-31     ResE
9  2019-02-09       B    2019-01-01  2099-12-31     ResF
6         NaT       B           NaT         NaT     ResG
```

Answer (score -1):

sql equivalent with where:

```
SELECT t1.company,
        t1.resource,
        t2.company,
        t2.resource,
        t1.ClockInDate,
        t2.EffectiveFrom,
        t2.EffectiveTo
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.resource = t2.resource
                    AND t1.company = t2.company
WHERE t1.ClockInDate IS NULL --no ClockInDate to check
    OR t2.company IS NULL AND t2.resource IS NULL --not rows in t2 for t1
    OR t1.ClockInDate BETWEEN t2.EffectiveFrom AND t2.EffectiveTo --ClockInDate exists, rows in t2 exist, we can now check ClockInDate to be between t2.EffectiveFrom AND t2.EffectiveTo
```

that would translate to python as:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Company', 'Resource'], how='left')
df_final = df_merge[df_merge.ClockInDate.isnull() | df_merge.ClockInDate.between(df_merge.EffectiveFrom, df_merge.EffectiveTo) | df_merge.EffectiveFrom.isnull()]
```

Comment: unfortunately your answer is incorrect. Like I already said in my question '_but it is not the same as including this after the join in the WHERE clause_'. It duplicates the rows in the output with Resource `ResG`, plus it returns the values from `EffectiveFrom` and `EffectiveTo` which should be `NULL` or `NaN`